# Atualização de aplicativo na Play Store

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic2, google-play, ionic3

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu tenho um aplicativo feito em cordova que publiquei ele na Play Store, esse aplicativo conseguiu alguns usuários...

Diante a demanda refiz o aplicativo do zero, utilizando Ionic 3 e subi ele na play store com a mesma assinatura alterando apenas as versões para que os usuarios recebam a atualização... a partir dessa atualização o seguinte tem ocorrido.

1. Se for o primeiro download do usuário, ele baixa a nova versão.. isso esta OK!
2. Se o usuário possuir a versão anterior, não aparece o botão de atualizar para ele, sendo necessário desinstalar o aplicativo e instalar novamente.
3. a Google Play não mandou notificação nem está atualizando o aplicativo de forma automática(para quem esta habilitado) sendo necessário a desinstalação e instalação novamente.

Estou preocupado pois estou perdendo usuários e o aplicativo esta assinado corretamente mediante as necessidades da Play Store.

Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? Agradeço desde ja...

Comment: Tem certeza que a versão estava correta? Eu já atualizei apps mudando de nativo para hibrido e deu tudo certo. Em uma atualização que fiz eu havia colocado um código de versão errado e o google alertou que os usuários não conseguiriam atualizar para a nova versão caso eu usasse aquele código, então alterei e deu tudo certo. Vai no menu Gerenciamento de versão > Versões de apps > Gerenciar produção > historico de versões e clica em cima de uma versão. Veja se o código da versão está certo. Lembre-se, tem versão (ex: 3.3.0) e código da versão (1,2,3,4), este deve ser sequencial

Comment: Em config.xml, você manteve o mesmo id e atualizou a versão?